# Moving to py2neo 2.0 and streaming

Tags: py2neo

I upgraded to py2neo 2.0 and the code I used for streaming and writing results to file doesn't work any more. The error I am getting is `TypeError: 'CypherResource' object is not callable`.

```
from py2neo import Graph
from py2neo.packages.httpstream import http
http.socket_timeout = 9999
graph = Graph()
query="""
MY QUERY
"""
result=graph.cypher(graph,query)
with open('myfile','w') as f:
    for record in result.stream():
        v=record.values
```

I assume the error is in graph.cypher(graph,query), but I was not successful in fixing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Graph.cypher` incorrectly. This is an object with execution and transaction management methods, not a callable itself. Please read the docs at:

http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html